# Hyperlink clickable on DataGridView

Tags: c#, sql

I have a site that has a list of other sites and links, I use Microsoft Visual Studio 2019 and Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, the connections work fine and I can view the data and update it, but one of the fields I want is a site URL, I didn't know how to create a field in the table that will take the input and store it as a hyperlink (this is possible in Access) but in SQL, so I want at least when used in detailview or gridview on the site for Users will see this file as hyperling so they can click on it instead of copying the url and putting it in explorer to access it.

I hope I'm asking the right way, so please if anyone can help, I really appreciate it.

Comment: you can create field with datatype varchar(length u need). is it windows application or web application ?

Comment: windows applications, but when I click on the link a web browser will be open

Comment: for opening browser to start process for that. var browser=new WebBrowser(); browser.NavigateURL(url, true)

Comment: Yes I know, but how can I do that when I click on a cell of datagridview, I can´t input the value of the link that I want into the cell, and transform that cell clickabel.

Comment: your gridview/datagrid must be bind with some collection in code behind. There will be some unique key for each row. Based on cell click , you can get the unique id of row clicked. Based on this get the URL from your collection and open that.

Comment: @MiguelSilva, please, show us your code